# Modular Dependency in my Docker "dnf module enabled -y php:7.4 php-oci8"

Tags: php, docker, oracle

So I'm running a command `dnf module enabled -y php:7.4 php-oci8`
but I'm getting a Modular Dependency Problem, this was not an issue before.

```
 Problem: module php-oci8:21c:8060020221011134100:34611983.x86_64 requires module(php:8.0), but none of the providers can be installed
  - module php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:8.0) provided by php:8.0:8060020211215065547:0a326c83.x86_64
  - module php:8.0:8060020211215065547:0a326c83.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:7.4) provided by php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64
  - module php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:8.0) provided by php:8.0:8060020220622070726:5caa48ff.x86_64
  - module php:8.0:8060020220622070726:5caa48ff.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:7.4) provided by php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64
  - module php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:8.0) provided by php:8.0:8070020220801083134:afd00e68.x86_64
  - module php:8.0:8070020220801083134:afd00e68.x86_64 conflicts with module(php:7.4) provided by php:7.4:8030020200615123046:a4870ff1.x86_64
  - conflicting requests
```

not really familiar on this things.

Comment: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php PHP 7.4 only has 9 days to go, so no surprise it is no longer being considered.

Comment: any tips whats needs to update?

Comment: Upgrade to 8.x as soon as you can, or any security issue can compromise your web apps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on my docker file first line

`FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-php:7.4-fpm`
change to
`FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-php:7.4-fpm-20221114`

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux8-php/48808020?tag=7.4-fpm-20221104